# ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sqlplus

I try to create table from ORACLE setup [script](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_compression-11gr2)
After I run the script

`SQL> @home/oracle/Desktop/Setup.sql`

Following output appears:

`Table dropped.
Table created.
Index created.
INSERT INTO tab1
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition
Commit complete.
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

And the table is created but it's empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an older article and it's assuming the year is 2015.
Change the script so partitions look like this:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (created_Date)
(PARTITION tab1_part_2017 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/01/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) TABLESPACE users,
 PARTITION tab1_part_2018 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) TABLESPACE users);
```

The whole script should look like this:

```
DROP TABLE tab1 PURGE;

CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  id                NUMBER,
  code              VARCHAR2(20),
  description       VARCHAR2(50),
  created_date      DATE,
  CONSTRAINT tab1_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (created_Date)
(PARTITION tab1_part_2017 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/01/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) TABLESPACE users,
 PARTITION tab1_part_2018 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) TABLESPACE users);

CREATE INDEX tab1_code_idx ON tab1(code) LOCAL;

INSERT INTO tab1
SELECT level,
       CASE
         WHEN MOD(level,2)=0 THEN 'CODE1'
         ELSE 'CODE2'
       END,
       CASE
         WHEN MOD(level,2)=0 THEN 'Description for CODE1'
         ELSE 'Description for CODE2'
       END,
       CASE
         WHEN MOD(level,2)=0 THEN SYSDATE
         ELSE ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 12)
       END
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 100000;
COMMIT;

EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(USER, 'TAB1');
```

This is because of this:

```
         WHEN MOD(level,2)=0 THEN SYSDATE
         ELSE ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 12)
```

SYSDATE will be inserted into tab1_part_2017 and ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 12) will be inserted into tab1_part_2018 and you will get equal number of rows in both partitions (50000 in each to be exact).